# How to find all references / peek definition / go to definition work across whole project

Tags: visual-studio-code

does anyone know how to make for example the "peek definition" feature of Visual Studio Code work in the entire project, hence across multiple files? Out of the box it only works when Stuff is in the same file.
Thank you :)

Also Intenseness do not seem to work across multiple files.

Comment: Depends on the language. For JS/TS it should work out of the box.

Comment: Thanks @Rob for your answer. It is JavaScript but it does not work out of the box. At least not for me??
I’m opening the project with `file > open` and then selecting the project folder… I got no intellisence nor this stuff mentioned above working across all files in the project…

Comment: Still no answer??

Comment: You should try updating to vscode 1.9. And what is the version number in the lower right corner of the status bar?

Comment: I’m on 1.9.0.. I’ve opened a ticket on github now, maybe they can help me there. So you are sure that no settings are required

Comment: Yes, but I mean you should see something like `JavaScript  2.1.5` which is actually the version number of the TS service used to provide intellisense, and I'm wondering what that is.

Comment: Yes, I have `JavaScript 2.1.6`